# How to push ViewController and have first controller partially visible?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController based application. I want to achieve an effect of presenting (pushing) view controller while having a part of a previous controller visible. So I want to have an effect like this:

[image]

Ideally the bottom of the second image would be a part of first controller's view.

Can this be done using UINavigationController methods, and if yes, how?

Comment: you must use Tabbarcontroller OR in the second view controller you just add one button bellow as you design  that first-view controller that is you can preset Firstviewcontroller using presentModelviewcontrolelr code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but it requires quite a bit of efford.

Off the top of my head, I'd implement a custom container view controller, that has a `UINavigationController` an another custom container view controller (let's call it `PreviousVCContainer`) as child view controllers. See [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6). The "inner container view controller" would provide the view on the bottom and have the previous view controller (the one with "First title") as child view controller.

The idea is to connect the `PreviousVCContainer` with the `UINavigationController` in a way that it gets notified when the navVC is pushing or popping a vc. It would then go and look for the appropriate vc to display in the bottom view and add this vc as it's childVC.

I hope that get's you started. Let me know if you need more details on some specific points.